# What would you call this large bowl-shaped container?

Tags: vocabulary, image-identification

[image]

What do you call this thing (on the picture)? Laundry and water is put in it.

Comment: Depends on the size, which you haven't indicated. If it's about half a metre across or a little more, I'd (UK) call it "a washing-up bowl".

Comment: Laundry can be put in it. Washing-up bowl? Ok, Thank you!

Comment: Doing a reverse image search, I find it listed on websites of some online shops as a `plastic wash basin`. Looking that up on Google Images, I find pictures of similar containers.

Comment: basin. But not a bowl: bowls are used in the kitchen and are generally smooth.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the size. "Basin" is probably the most appropriate term for a very large, relatively shallow bowl-shaped container. If it's small, it's a bowl or a dish, depending on the intended use and where you live.

Without scale and context, it's hard to say what the proper term is.